# Integrating an implicit derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, implicit-differentiation

This is related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755736/awkward-triple-integral), which I have managed to re-formulate but still cannot solve. It's a physics/mechanics problem I'm working on. It may well be the case that I am not Googling the right terms to find the solution, so please correct me if this is the case.

My function is implicitly defined as follows:
$$F(r,z,b) = \frac{3r^2 - a}{(r^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{3az^2}{(r^2+z^2)^{5/2}} - b = 0$$
where $a$ is a real constant greater than zero, $b>0$ and $a<r^2$.

I first need to find gradient of $z(r)$ with respect to $b$, and then integrate the resulting gradient function with respect to $r$. i.e.:
$\int \frac{dz}{db}dr$.

I can find the gradient $dz/db$ easily enough using implicit differentiation:
$$\frac{dz}{db} = -\frac{\left(r^2+z^2\right)^{7/2}}{a \left(6 z^3-9 r^2 z\right)+9 r^2 z \left(r^2+z^2\right)}$$

But how I can easily integrate this w.r.t. $r$, given that $z$ is itself a function of $r$ (in that they are both defined in the original implicit equation)?

Ultimately I need a result that depends only on $a$ and $r$ such that I can compute the integral between limits (i.e. $z$ needs to disappear).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation

Comment: @Idlewild could you please explain a little how to use the integral equation in this context?

Comment: Another possibility is to approximate my function with something that is easier to manipulate. However, as the function is a polynomial, what could I approximate it with?